# I have exported an Excel from HTML table, but in the Excel I see the drop menu, text box are drawn. I need only the values

Tags: html, xml, html-table, spreadsheet

This is the JS section of the code. To create the Excel from the HTM table. I see Text box, Radio buttons created in the excel sheet. I need to remove them and I need only the text value. Is there any XML tag to remove the Text box and other elements from the Excel sheet.

```
<script>

var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]>    
<xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}
</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()

</script>
```